# documentclass using amsmath, without sections

Tags: sectioning, document-classes

It's probably true that, thousands of times every day, someone somewhere writes a short explanation of some mathematical phenomenon, using equations, including alignment possibilities, lemmas and theorems. It's useful to use amsmath, but it's pointless and inappropriate to use sections in a short document.

Here's my question: I want my first lemma to be numbered LEMMA 1, but, whatever I try, I get the annoying LEMMA 0.1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which document class?

Comment: It is also annoying that every day people ask questions without a minimal example which could be used for tests.

Comment: If you simply declare `\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}` and then use `\begin{lem}`...`\end{lem}` it doesn't happen.

Comment: @karlkoeller: Your first comment: I tried many different standard document classes and they all behaved the same way. Your second comment: Your suggestion of using \newtheorem answers my question. Thank you. How can I accept that as a good answer?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: thanks for the good advice. I'll try to remember to include a MWE in future posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely you have declared your lemma numbering to be within section numbering, that is, something like

```
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
```

In fact, the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{lem}
  Hello
\end{lem}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Instead, you have to define it to not follow any existing counter:

```
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
```

In this case, the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\begin{document}
\begin{lem}
  Hello
\end{lem}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: In fact, the amsmath package includes something equivalent to \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]. It would be nice to know how to claw back from amsmath these definitions of new theorems. But I'll refrain from asking another question about how to do this. There doesn't seem to be any command like \renewtheorem.